# Play2 Framework Template parameters

Tags: java, web, frameworks, playframework

I'm trying to develop a template which has the content in the middle (link the main.scala.html) of the page.

Here is my Codes

The Template of the mainPage (name: test.scala.html)

```
    @(title: String)(content: Html)

      <p> Some HTML Stuff </p>
        @content
```

The secon Page (name: test2.scala.html)

```
@(test:String)
 @test("test2"){
  <p> Hello World </p>
}
```

The controller

```
public class Admin extends Controller {

    public static Result test(){           
        return ok(test.render("test"));
    }


    public static Result test2(){
        return ok(test2.render("test2"));
    }

}
```

On this way it don't work. May be there is somebody who can help me

Comment: have you specified the routes and corresponding handlers in routes.conf

Comment: jup, the routes are ok

Comment: Can you elaborate what doesn't work? What error message(s) are you seeing?

Comment: The testcontroller needs a html-argument and i get an error when I use the @test("") notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this must be a compile error, because your template requires two arguments.

```
//scala template
@(title: String)(content: Html)

  <p> Some HTML Stuff </p>
    @content

// java call
public static Result test(){           
    return ok(test.render("test"));
}
```

you have to pass some Html to the test template

your java call could be like

```
return ok(test.render("test",test2.render("test2")));
```

but in your case you should just call the test2 template, because your test-template is more like a wrapper.